# Drush 8.1.9+ with Drupal 6 results in "Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error" followed by the site home page source code

Tags: 6, drush

My sites are hosted on a Linux server with Apache 2.2, PHP 5.5, MySQL 5.6 installed. I use Drush 8.1.8 which I installed via composer and which works correctly with my D6, D7 and D8 sites. I can update some D6 site modules by using Drush 8 combined with the myDropWizard module.

I've recently tried to update Drush to 8.1.9 version then to 8.1.10 version, but none works with the D6 sites, while still working correctly with the D7 and D8 sites.

Each time I try to use a Drush command for a D6 site, this message is displayed:

> Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.   [error]

It is weirdly followed by the display of the whole home page source code of this site.

I've also tried reproducing this on localhost; in that case, Drush is stuck and displays nothing.

Does Drush 8 still work with Drupal 6?

**Edit:**

`[~/public_html/en/sites/en.mysite.com]# drush -dv up`

Passed with Drush 8.1.8:

```
Using the Drush script found at /home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.launcher using proc_open
Drush preflight prepare loaded autoloader at                         [preflight]
/home/myuser/.composer/vendor/autoload.php [0.01 sec, 2.5 MB]
Starting Drush preflight. [0.01 sec, 2.5 MB]                         [preflight]
Loading drushrc "/home/myuser/.drush/drushrc.php" into "home.drush"[bootstrap]
scope. [0.01 sec, 2.8 MB]
Cache HIT cid: 8.1.8-commandfiles-0-6f2a323a6de1242729a7e3fe6aad3d20     [debug]
[0.02 sec, 2.86 MB]
Scanning into /etc/drush for /.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.07        [debug]
sec, 5.56 MB]
Scanning into /etc/drush for /self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.07      [debug]
sec, 5.56 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/..    [debug]
for /.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.07 sec, 5.56 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/..    [debug]
for /self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.07 sec, 5.56 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/.drush for                                  [debug]
/.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.08 sec, 5.56 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/.drush for                                  [debug]
/self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.08 sec, 5.56 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/public_html/en/../drush for                 [debug]
/.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.08 sec, 5.57 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/public_html/en/../drush for                 [debug]
/self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.08 sec, 5.57 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/public_html/en/drush for                    [debug]
/.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.08 sec, 5.57 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/public_html/en/drush for                    [debug]
/self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.08 sec, 5.57 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/public_html/en/sites/all/drush for          [debug]
/.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.08 sec, 5.57 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/public_html/en/sites/all/drush for          [debug]
/self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.08 sec, 5.57 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/public_html/en/sites/default for            [debug]
/.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.08 sec, 5.57 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/public_html/en/sites/default for            [debug]
/self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.08 sec, 5.57 MB]
Bootstrap to phase 0. [0.25 sec, 9.19 MB]                            [bootstrap]
Bootstrap to phase 6. [0.26 sec, 9.2 MB]                             [bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_root() [0.26 sec, 9.57 MB]  [bootstrap]
Initialized Drupal 6.38 root directory at                            [bootstrap]
/home/myuser/public_html/en [0.27 sec, 9.74 MB]
Find command files for phase 1 (max=6) [0.28 sec, 7.06 MB]               [debug]
Cache MISS cid: 8.1.8-commandfiles-1-b9fee8b15dbf25a4d90112dcde868368    [debug]
[0.28 sec, 7.06 MB]
Cache SET cid: 8.1.8-commandfiles-1-b9fee8b15dbf25a4d90112dcde868368     [debug]
[0.28 sec, 7.06 MB]
Cache MISS cid:                                                          [debug]
8.1.8-annotationfiles-1-90bcfd4c83aa04b96148e19f9b6d112b [0.28 sec,
7.06 MB]
Cache SET cid:                                                           [debug]
8.1.8-annotationfiles-1-90bcfd4c83aa04b96148e19f9b6d112b [0.28 sec,
7.06 MB]
Scanning into /etc/drush for /.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.28        [debug]
sec, 7.07 MB]
Scanning into /etc/drush for /self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.28      [debug]
sec, 7.07 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/..    [debug]
for /.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.28 sec, 7.07 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/..    [debug]
for /self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.28 sec, 7.07 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/.drush for                                  [debug]
/.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.29 sec, 7.07 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/.drush for                                  [debug]
/self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.29 sec, 7.08 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/public_html/en/../drush for                 [debug]
/.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.29 sec, 7.08 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/public_html/en/../drush for                 [debug]
/self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.29 sec, 7.08 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/public_html/en/drush for                    [debug]
/.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.29 sec, 7.08 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/public_html/en/drush for                    [debug]
/self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.29 sec, 7.08 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/public_html/en/sites/all/drush for          [debug]
/.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.29 sec, 7.08 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/public_html/en/sites/all/drush for          [debug]
/self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.29 sec, 7.09 MB]
Scanning into                                                            [debug]
/home/myuser/public_html/en/sites/en.mysite.com for
/.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.29 sec, 7.09 MB]
Scanning into                                                            [debug]
/home/myuser/public_html/en/sites/en.mysite.com for
/self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.29 sec, 7.09 MB]
Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_site() [0.3 sec, 7.09 MB]   [bootstrap]
Initialized Drupal site en.mysite.com at                   [bootstrap]
sites/en.mysite.com [0.3 sec, 7.09 MB]
Find command files for phase 2 (max=6) [0.3 sec, 7.09 MB]                [debug]
Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_configuration() [0.3 sec,   [bootstrap]
7.09 MB]
Find command files for phase 3 (max=6) [0.3 sec, 7.1 MB]                 [debug]
sql-query: SELECT 1; [0.31 sec, 7.25 MB]                                [notice]
Executing: mysql --defaults-extra-file=/tmp/drush_OIe8xv --database=myuser_dru600en-3 --host=localhost --silent  < /tmp/drush_9CYvzv
  1
sql-query: SHOW TABLES; [0.32 sec, 7.25 MB]                             [notice]
Executing: mysql --defaults-extra-file=/tmp/drush_8JGzyv --database=myuser_dru600en-3 --host=localhost --silent  < /tmp/drush_dAplyv

----------

Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_database() [0.34 sec, 7.28  [bootstrap]
MB]
Successfully connected to the Drupal database. [0.34 sec, 7.49 MB]   [bootstrap]
Find command files for phase 4 (max=6) [0.34 sec, 7.49 MB]               [debug]
Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_full() [0.34 sec, 7.49 MB]  [bootstrap]
session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by[1;33;40m[1m[warning][0m
(output started at
/home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/output.inc:41)
bootstrap.inc:1182 [0.34 sec, 7.53 MB]
session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already [1;33;40m[1m[warning][0m
sent (output started at
/home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/output.inc:41)
bootstrap.inc:1182 [0.34 sec, 7.53 MB]
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output   [1;33;40m[1m[warning][0m
started at
/home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/output.inc:41)
bootstrap.inc:736 [0.36 sec, 9.19 MB]
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output   [1;33;40m[1m[warning][0m
started at
/home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/output.inc:41)
bootstrap.inc:737 [0.36 sec, 9.19 MB]
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output   [1;33;40m[1m[warning][0m
started at
/home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/output.inc:41)
bootstrap.inc:738 [0.36 sec, 9.19 MB]
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output   [1;33;40m[1m[warning][0m
started at
/home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/output.inc:41)
bootstrap.inc:739 [0.37 sec, 9.19 MB]
Cache MISS cid:                                                          [debug]
8.1.8-install_profile-e90a16a83d52c8b645801f9d680294e7 [0.64 sec,
27.29 MB]
Cache SET cid: 8.1.8-install_profile-e90a16a83d52c8b645801f9d680294e7    [debug]
[0.64 sec, 27.29 MB]
Find command files for phase 5 (max=6) [0.64 sec, 27.3 MB]               [debug]
Cache HIT cid: 8.1.8-install_profile-e90a16a83d52c8b645801f9d680294e7    [debug]
[0.64 sec, 27.3 MB]
Cache MISS cid: 8.1.8-commandfiles-5-a9080126c9c73166bca2cdbd6b3b0237    [debug]
[0.65 sec, 27.43 MB]
Cache SET cid: 8.1.8-commandfiles-5-a9080126c9c73166bca2cdbd6b3b0237     [debug]
[0.74 sec, 27.44 MB]
Cache MISS cid:                                                          [debug]
8.1.8-annotationfiles-5-fa617a1a276a4dad2c17877d766b9665 [0.76 sec,
27.81 MB]
Cache SET cid:                                                           [debug]
8.1.8-annotationfiles-5-fa617a1a276a4dad2c17877d766b9665 [0.76 sec,
27.81 MB]
Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_login() [0.77 sec, 27.77 MB][bootstrap]
Find command files for phase 6 (max=6) [0.77 sec, 27.8 MB]               [debug]
Found command: pm-update (commandfile=pm) [0.77 sec, 27.8 MB]        [bootstrap]
Calling hook drush_pm_update [0.94 sec, 31.04 MB]                        [debug]
Loading release_info engine. [0.94 sec, 31.08 MB]                       [notice]
Loading version_control engine. [0.94 sec, 31.08 MB]                    [notice]
Loading package_handler engine. [0.94 sec, 31.1 MB]                     [notice]
Executing: wget --version
Loading update_status engine. [0.95 sec, 31.09 MB]                      [notice]
Including                                                            [bootstrap]
/home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/commands/pm/updatecode.pm.inc
[0.96 sec, 31.09 MB]
Calling hook drush_pm_updatecode_validate [0.96 sec, 31.19 MB]           [debug]
Returned from hook drush_pm_updatecode_validate [0.96 sec, 31.2 MB]      [debug]
Calling hook drush_pm_updatecode [0.97 sec, 31.21 MB]                    [debug]
Cache MISS cid: 8.1.8-alias-path--03cb329adb374664ee9dca020716dbe1       [debug]
[0.97 sec, 31.24 MB]
Scanning into /etc/drush for /.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.97        [debug]
sec, 31.24 MB]
Scanning into /etc/drush for /.*\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.97        [debug]
sec, 31.24 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/..    [debug]
for /.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.97 sec, 31.24 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/..    [debug]
for /.*\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.97 sec, 31.25 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/.drush for                                  [debug]
/.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.98 sec, 31.25 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/.drush for                                  [debug]
/.*\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.98 sec, 31.25 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/public_html/en/drush for                    [debug]
/.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.98 sec, 31.25 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/public_html/en/drush for                    [debug]
/.*\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.98 sec, 31.25 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/public_html/en/sites/all/drush for          [debug]
/.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.98 sec, 31.25 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/public_html/en/sites/all/drush for          [debug]
/.*\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.98 sec, 31.26 MB]
Scanning into                                                            [debug]
/home/myuser/public_html/en/sites/en.mysite.com for
/.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.98 sec, 31.26 MB]
Scanning into                                                            [debug]
/home/myuser/public_html/en/sites/en.mysite.com for
/.*\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.98 sec, 31.26 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/public_html/en/../drush for                 [debug]
/.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.98 sec, 31.26 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/public_html/en/../drush for                 [debug]
/.*\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.98 sec, 31.26 MB]
Cache SET cid: 8.1.8-alias-path--03cb329adb374664ee9dca020716dbe1        [debug]
[0.99 sec, 31.28 MB]
Backend invoke: /usr/bin/php-cli                                       [command]
/home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php
--php=/usr/bin/php-cli  --backend=2 --verbose --debug
--root=/home/myuser/public_html/en
--uri=http://en.mysite.com
--db-url='mysql://myuser_en:en123@localhost/myuser_dru600en-3' 
pm-updatestatus 2>&1 [0.99 sec, 31.27 MB]
/usr/bin/php-cli                                                        [notice]
/home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php
--php=/usr/bin/php-cli  --backend=2 --verbose --debug
--root=/home/myuser/public_html/en
--uri=http://en.mysite.com
--db-url='mysql://myuser_en:en123@localhost/myuser_dru600en-3' 
pm-updatestatus 2>&1 [0.99 sec, 31.27 MB]
Update information last refreshed: February 26, 2017 - 12:14

----------
```

Failed with Drush 8.1.10:

```
Using the Drush script found at /home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.launcher using proc_open
Drush preflight prepare loaded autoloader at                         [preflight]
/home/myuser/.composer/vendor/autoload.php [0.01 sec, 2.5 MB]
Starting Drush preflight. [0.01 sec, 2.5 MB]                         [preflight]
Loading drushrc "/home/myuser/.drush/drushrc.php" into "home.drush"[bootstrap]
scope. [0.01 sec, 2.8 MB]
Cache HIT cid: 8.1.10-commandfiles-0-6f2a323a6de1242729a7e3fe6aad3d20    [debug]
[0.02 sec, 2.86 MB]
Scanning into /etc/drush for /.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.07        [debug]
sec, 5.56 MB]
Scanning into /etc/drush for /self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.07      [debug]
sec, 5.56 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/..    [debug]
for /.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.07 sec, 5.56 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/..    [debug]
for /self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.08 sec, 5.56 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/.drush for                                  [debug]
/.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.08 sec, 5.56 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/.drush for                                  [debug]
/self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.08 sec, 5.57 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/public_html/en/../drush for                 [debug]
/.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.08 sec, 5.57 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/public_html/en/../drush for                 [debug]
/self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.08 sec, 5.57 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/public_html/en/drush for                    [debug]
/.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.09 sec, 5.57 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/public_html/en/drush for                    [debug]
/self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.09 sec, 5.57 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/public_html/en/sites/all/drush for          [debug]
/.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.09 sec, 5.57 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/public_html/en/sites/all/drush for          [debug]
/self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.09 sec, 5.57 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/public_html/en/sites/default for            [debug]
/.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.09 sec, 5.58 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/public_html/en/sites/default for            [debug]
/self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.09 sec, 5.58 MB]
Bootstrap to phase 0. [0.27 sec, 9.53 MB]                            [bootstrap]
Bootstrap to phase 6. [0.27 sec, 9.54 MB]                            [bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_root() [0.28 sec, 9.91 MB]  [bootstrap]
Initialized Drupal 6.38 root directory at                            [bootstrap]
/home/myuser/public_html/en [0.28 sec, 10.08 MB]
Find command files for phase 1 (max=6) [0.29 sec, 7.37 MB]               [debug]
Cache HIT cid: 8.1.10-commandfiles-1-b9fee8b15dbf25a4d90112dcde868368    [debug]
[0.29 sec, 7.37 MB]
Cache HIT cid:                                                           [debug]
8.1.10-annotationfiles-1-90bcfd4c83aa04b96148e19f9b6d112b [0.29 sec,
7.37 MB]
Scanning into /etc/drush for /.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.29        [debug]
sec, 7.38 MB]
Scanning into /etc/drush for /self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.29      [debug]
sec, 7.38 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/..    [debug]
for /.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.29 sec, 7.38 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/..    [debug]
for /self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.3 sec, 7.38 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/.drush for                                  [debug]
/.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.3 sec, 7.39 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/.drush for                                  [debug]
/self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.3 sec, 7.39 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/public_html/en/../drush for                 [debug]
/.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.31 sec, 7.39 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/public_html/en/../drush for                 [debug]
/self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.31 sec, 7.39 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/public_html/en/drush for                    [debug]
/.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.31 sec, 7.39 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/public_html/en/drush for                    [debug]
/self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.31 sec, 7.39 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/public_html/en/sites/all/drush for          [debug]
/.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.31 sec, 7.4 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/public_html/en/sites/all/drush for          [debug]
/self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.31 sec, 7.4 MB]
Scanning into                                                            [debug]
/home/myuser/public_html/en/sites/en.mysite.com for
/.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.31 sec, 7.4 MB]
Scanning into                                                            [debug]
/home/myuser/public_html/en/sites/en.mysite.com for
/self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.31 sec, 7.4 MB]
Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_site() [0.31 sec, 7.4 MB]   [bootstrap]
Initialized Drupal site en.mysite.com at                   [bootstrap]
sites/en.mysite.com [0.31 sec, 7.4 MB]
Find command files for phase 2 (max=6) [0.31 sec, 7.4 MB]                [debug]
Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_configuration() [0.31 sec,  [bootstrap]
7.4 MB]
Find command files for phase 3 (max=6) [0.32 sec, 7.41 MB]               [debug]
sql-query: SELECT 1; [0.32 sec, 7.56 MB]                                [notice]
Executing: mysql --defaults-extra-file=/tmp/drush_0zQeYL --database=myuser_dru600en-3 --host=localhost --silent  < /tmp/drush_yLhbDp
  1
sql-query: SHOW TABLES; [0.33 sec, 7.56 MB]                             [notice]
Executing: mysql --defaults-extra-file=/tmp/drush_gUe2Gu --database=myuser_dru600en-3 --host=localhost --silent  < /tmp/drush_CJUCk8
  access
  accesslog
  actions
  actions_aid
  advanced_help_index
  aggregator_category
  aggregator_category_feed
  aggregator_category_item
  aggregator_feed
  aggregator_item
  antispam_counter
  antispam_moderator
  antispam_spam_marks
  authmap
  bad_behavior_log
  batch
  better_formats_defaults
  blocks
  blocks_roles
  book
  boxes
  cache
  cache_block
  cache_content
  cache_emfield_xml
  cache_filter
  cache_form
  cache_media_youtube_status
  cache_menu
  cache_mollom
  cache_mydropwizard
  cache_page
  cache_panels
  cache_update
  cache_views
  cache_views_data
  captcha_points
  captcha_sessions
  client
  client_system
  comment_notify
  comment_notify_user_settings
  comments
  contact
  contemplate
  contemplate_files
  content_field_additional_information
  content_field_description
  content_field_illustration
  content_field_rubric
  content_group
  content_group_fields
  content_node_field
  content_node_field_instance
  content_type_book
  content_type_content_publication
  content_type_event
  content_type_illustration
  content_type_image
  content_type_issue
  content_type_meeting
  content_type_page
  content_type_panel
  content_type_podcast
  content_type_simplenews
  content_type_story
  content_type_video
  content_type_weblink
  ctools_css_cache
  ctools_object_cache
  date_format_locale
  date_format_types
  date_formats
  discussthis
  discussthis_forums
  drupal_install_test
  excerpt
  fb_app
  fb_user
  filefield_paths
  files
  filestore2
  filter_formats
  filters
  flood
  forum
  fscache
  history
  imagecache_action
  imagecache_preset
  imce_files
  inline
  languages
  links
  links_monitor
  links_node
  locales_meta
  locales_source
  locales_target
  media_youtube_metadata
  media_youtube_node_data
  menu_custom
  menu_links
  menu_router
  moderation_filters
  moderation_roles
  moderation_votes
  mollom
  mollom_form
  node
  node_access
  node_comment_statistics
  node_counter
  node_revisions
  node_type
  nodequeue_nodes
  nodequeue_queue
  nodequeue_roles
  nodequeue_subqueue
  nodequeue_types
  nodewords
  old_revisions
  openid_association
  openid_nonce
  page_manager_handlers
  page_manager_pages
  page_manager_weights
  panels_display
  panels_layout
  panels_mini
  panels_node
  panels_pane
  panels_renderer_pipeline
  path_redirect
  permission
  pm_index
  pm_message
  poll
  poll_choices
  poll_votes
  print_mail_node_conf
  print_mail_page_counter
  print_node_conf
  print_page_counter
  profile_fields
  profile_values
  queue
  relatedlinks
  relatedlinks_tracker
  role
  search_dataset
  search_index
  search_keywords_log
  search_node_links
  search_total
  security_review
  semaphore
  sequences
  sessions
  simplenews_mail_spool
  simplenews_newsletters
  simplenews_scheduler
  simplenews_scheduler_editions
  simplenews_snid_tid
  simplenews_subscriptions
  stylizer
  system
  taxonomy_context_term
  taxonomy_context_vocabulary
  taxonomy_manager_merge
  term_autotagging_data
  term_data
  term_hierarchy
  term_node
  term_relation
  term_synonym
  upload
  url_alias
  users
  users_roles
  variable
  view_argument
  view_exposed_filter
  view_filter
  view_sort
  view_tablefield
  view_view
  views_data_export
  views_data_export_object_cache
  views_display
  views_object_cache
  views_view
  vocabulary
  vocabulary_node_types
  watchdog
  webform
  webform_component
  webform_emails
  webform_last_download
  webform_roles
  webform_submissions
  webform_submitted_data
  weblink
  weblinks
  weblinks_node
  wysiwyg
  wysiwyg_user
  xmlsitemap
  xmlsitemap_sitemap
  xmlsitemap_term
Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_database() [0.35 sec, 7.6   [bootstrap]
MB]
Successfully connected to the Drupal database. [0.36 sec, 7.8 MB]    [bootstrap]
Find command files for phase 4 (max=6) [0.36 sec, 7.8 MB]                [debug]
Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_full() [0.36 sec, 7.8 MB]   [bootstrap]
session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by[1;33;40m[1m[warning][0m
(output started at
/home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/output.inc:41)
bootstrap.inc:1182 [0.36 sec, 7.84 MB]
session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already [1;33;40m[1m[warning][0m
sent (output started at
/home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/output.inc:41)
bootstrap.inc:1182 [0.36 sec, 7.85 MB]
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output   [1;33;40m[1m[warning][0m
started at
/home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/output.inc:41)
bootstrap.inc:770 [0.38 sec, 9.5 MB]
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output   [1;33;40m[1m[warning][0m
started at
/home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/output.inc:41)
bootstrap.inc:771 [0.38 sec, 9.5 MB]
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output   [1;33;40m[1m[warning][0m
started at
/home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/output.inc:41)
bootstrap.inc:774 [0.38 sec, 9.5 MB]
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output   [1;33;40m[1m[warning][0m
started at
/home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/output.inc:41)
bootstrap.inc:775 [0.38 sec, 9.5 MB]
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output   [1;33;40m[1m[warning][0m
started at
/home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/output.inc:41)
bootstrap.inc:797 [0.38 sec, 9.5 MB]
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output   [1;33;40m[1m[warning][0m
started at
/home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/output.inc:41)
bootstrap.inc:797 [0.38 sec, 9.5 MB]
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.   [31;40m[1m[error][0m
[0.38 sec, 9.53 MB]
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <title>Site off-line | </title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/files/en/css/css_efc0c05aa0cad4c9108b9319f85db325.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="/files/en/css/css_27bf2b59a4b65e1feaeb43135d7e990a.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/files/en/js/js_d2fed660346f255db8897c2b7ca69b33.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings, { "basePath": "/", "fb_connect": { "front_url": "/", "fbu": 0, "uid": 0 }, "nice_menus_options": { "delay": 800, "speed": 1 } });
//--><!]]>
</script>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/themes/garland/fix-ie.css" />    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>

<!-- Layout -->
  <div id="header-region" class="clear-block"></div>

    <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container" class="clear-block">

      <div id="header">
        <div id="logo-floater">
        <h1><a href="/" title=" mysite!"><span></span> mysite!</a></h1>        </div>

      </div> <!-- /header -->


      <div id="center"><div id="squeeze"><div class="right-corner"><div class="left-corner">
          <h2>Site off-line</h2>                              <div class="clear-block">
            down for maintenance          </div>
          <div id="footer"></div>
      </div></div></div></div> <!-- /.left-corner, /.right-corner, /#squeeze, /#center -->


    </div> <!-- /container -->
  </div>
<!-- /layout -->

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/#drupal-compatibility), yes. If you feel it does not, it might be a bug.

Comment: It's a bit more likely to be an error in the site somewhere, but you can confirm easily enough by installing an older version of drush and seeing if you have the same issue

Comment: This issue only occurs with 8.1.9+ versions. No problem with the 8.1.8 and previous ones.

Comment: The `drush -dv up` results have been added to the question.

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when some code calls `exit()`, e.g. due to a redirect. Any call to `exit()` or `drupal_goto()` must be guarded by `php_sapi_name() === 'cli'` so that it is never called from Drush. You can see that the [tests for the 8.x branch are still passing for Drupal 6](https://travis-ci.org/drush-ops/drush/builds/204737366).

Comment: Looking at the results of the `drush -dv up` command (now added to the question), I don't really know where to start investigating. Any further advice would be most welcome!

Comment: 8.1.8 results, line 43: 2 times "Cache MISS cid ... Cache SET cid", line 334: "Cache MISS cid ... Cache SET cid ... Cache HIT cid ... "; 8.1.10 results, line 43: 2 times "Cache HIT cid", line 337: "Drush error" instead of the expected "Cache ... cid". Is a cache issue conceivable?